# Missing vccorlib140_app.dll and many more. Trying to load .dll in matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, dll, uwp

I have written a .dll which I'd like to load with matlab. When I load it with loadlibrary() in matlab I get an error stating that some modules were not found. I then checked with the Dependencies and found that several .dlls were missing:

[Dependencies (x64): missing vccorlib140_app.dll and many more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eev39.png)

However, I can't find any of this .dlls on my machine. Any ideas?

Comment: I believe these are possible false positives.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using to build your `.dll`? Is it Visual Studio 2015 to 2019?

Comment: An error like that often means you compiled your DLL for WinRT platform but trying to use it in Win32 mode. You need to recreate your .DLL Project as a Windows Desktop Project.

Comment: @drescherjm I am using 2019.

Comment: @rustyx I am currently using the DLL (Universal Windows) Template from Visual Studio. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: You have to make sure you don't use any template that says Universal, UWP or WinRT. Those are for Microsoft Store apps - something else entirely.

Comment: @rustyx Thanks, can I still use UWP APIs with a Windows Desktop Project? I need the RacingWheel Class from UWP. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Gaming.Input.RacingWheel?view=winrt-19041